# Error while sign up with github using python social auth : Internal Server Error: /sso/social/complete/github/

Tags: python, django, github-api, python-social-auth

I have implemented sign up with github in my project.These are the pipelnes used :

```
 SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'accounts.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'accounts.pipeline.user.non_internal_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'accounts.pipeline.user.populate_additional_info',
    'accounts.pipeline.user.user_accept_terms',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'accounts.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

set up the keys in the project after generating them in github applications

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_KEY = 'random403453'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET = 'randomexample3'
```

In github applications :

```
My homepage url : https://example.org
My call back url : https://example.org
```

I get this error

```
"/opt/virtualenvs/pyapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py",
> line 351, in process_error
> data'error')
> AuthFailed: Authentication failed: The code passed is incorrect or expired.
>
> Request repr():
> <WSGIRequest
> path:/sso/social/complete/github/,
> GET:<QueryDict:
{u'state': [u'D6cGrandomHEnt6oLR'], u'code': > [u'9arandom29886f7'], u'redirect_state': > [u'D6crandoma2MQa5HEnt6oLR']}
```

Went through this url https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls .Found out similar error listed out there.This error occurs rarely and I am not able to reproduce it.How can i reproduce this error or catch this ?